# How do you reference a value within a previous filtered row in a DAX formula?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working on a fitness dashboard which provides a 'performance' score across different exercises.

In the provided screenshot, you can see a table which shows me an averaged daily 'performance' result for 'deadlifts' for example.

Obviously, I don't do these every day, so there are gaps between the dates for which I have records.

What I want is to be able to produce a '% improvement vs last recorded day' measure. Is it possible to create a measure that runs a comparison of this sort?

[image: illustrative screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table look like this

```
Table
+-------------------+-------------+
|        Date       | Performance |
+-------------------+-------------+
| 02 September 2020 | 20          |
+-------------------+-------------+
| 08 September 2020 | 20          |
+-------------------+-------------+
| 14 September 2020 | 20          |
+-------------------+-------------+
| 25 September 2020 | 32          |
+-------------------+-------------+
| 26 October 2020   | 36          |
+-------------------+-------------+
```

I have created a calculation that would scans the table for the last available date besides the

Steps:

1. Get the current value on each row. For example, 1st row is 2 of September. The value is stored in `_SelectedValue`
2. Use `MAX` to calculate the nearest value excluding the `_SelectedValue`. Save the result in `MaxDate`.
3. Using the 3rd step, filter the table to get the sum of performance for `MaxDate`.
4. Get the Percentage difference

```
Performance Calculation =
VAR _SelectedValue =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Date] )
VAR MaxDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ),
        FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Date] < _SelectedValue )
    )
VAR PreviousPerformance =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Performance] ),
        FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Date] = MaxDate )
    )
VAR CurrentPerformance =
    SUM ( 'Table'[Performance] )
VAR Result =
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( MaxDate ),
        BLANK (),
        DIVIDE ( CurrentPerformance - PreviousPerformance, PreviousPerformance )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks Angelo. Like your approach :). Unfortunately it hasn't worked because the 'performance' data is a calculated measure. It isn't a table column. (Replacing the references to 'SUM ( 'Table'[Performance] )' with the measure doesn't fix the issue. Basically the data is coming from a data table which is linked to an 'Exercise Log' table. The 'performance' measure is calculated based on a combination of fields in the exercise log (i.e weights, reps, sets) which is then compared to some benchmark data in another linked table. Hmm it seems impossible to add spaces in this comment...

Comment: The calculation works with measures, the problem you could encounter is the filter context. Please update your question with your full data model to provide a proper answer.